# mvc3 passing button name to post

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

The button name is not being passed to my action method.

Here is my view (simplified):

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("HandleSubmit", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{    
    <input id="btnAddLineItem" type="submit" name="AddLineItem" value="AddLineItem" />
}
```

Here's the controller method:

```
[HttpPost, ActionName("HandleSubmit")]
public ActionResult HandleSubmit(int? id, string btnSubmit)
{
    switch (btnSubmit)
    {
        case "AddLineItem":
            break;
        case "AddNewOrder":
            break;
    }

    return View("OrderDetails");
}
```

The btnSubmit value is always null. What do I need to do differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `name` is what gets bound to your method signature, not the `id`.

Use the following:

```
public ActionResult HandleSubmit(string AddLineItem, string AddNewOrder)
{
    /* ... code ... */

    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(AddLineItem)) {

    }
    else if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(AddNewOrder)) {

    }

    /* ... code ... */
}
```

Remember the form post will send a `multipart/form-data` collection of `name/value` pairs to the server.

Answer (score 0):

You are not sending the button ID in any name or value in way whatsoever.

I suggest you make a model that has the following two properties:

In the get method make an instance of the model:

```
    public ActionResult HandleSubmit()
    {
        MyModel model = new MyModel();
        return View(model);
    }
```

In the post method use the property of the model to get your values.

```
    [HttpPost, ActionName("HandleSubmit")]
    public ActionResult HandleSubmit(MyModel model)
    {
        switch (model.Order)
        {
            case "AddLineItem":
                break;
            case "AddNewOrder":
                break;
        }

        return View("OrderDetails");
    }
```

Your view can be something like the following:

```
@model MvcApplication3.Controllers.MyModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("HandleSubmit", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{    
  @Html.EditorFor(x => Model.Order)
  <input id="btnAddLineItem" type="submit" name="AddLineItem" value="AddLineItem" />
}
```